# Notice: Undefined Offset: 0

Tags: php

I am trying to get a value from an array, but when I use `$array[0]`, I get a PHP notice 'Undefined Offset: 0'. However, when I use `$array['id']` (should be the same as using '0', since 'id' is the first key in the array), I am able to get the value. I did a print_r and this was outputted:

```
Array ( 
     [id] => 1 
     [username] => test 
)
```

Shouldn't I be able to get the key using its index? I believe it was working earlier, but I don't know what I could have done to make it stop working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't be able to do this.

You might be thinking of arrays obtained from something like [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array), which, by default, lets you use both numeric and string indexes to get to the columns - but the reason you can do that is because the array contains *both* of those.

You can also use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to extract values from an array to essentially transform the indexes to numeric ones, but it's not the same thing, really.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking of

Answer (score 2):

`$array['id']` is **not** the same as `$array[0]`. This confusion is probably related because of the term *array*. php's arrays aren't what you'd call an array in another language, they are *maps* or *dictionaries*.

(Oh, and even if they were not, the order of elements in a php array, a map, or a dictionary is up to the implementation, so while you'll get the id with `$tmp = array_values($array); echo $tmp[0];`, php is allowed to shuffle the array around).